# WekaForecaster Graph Access

Tags: time-series, weka, timeserieschart

Is it possible to access the graphs produced by WekaForecaster API as visible in Weka Explorer. I see that the API per se does not have any function access. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the answer.

1. Create a TSEvaluation object
2. Call evaluateForecaster(TSForecaster forecaster, boolean buildModel, java.io.PrintStream... progress)
3. Call graphFutureForecastOnTesting(GraphDriver driver, TSForecaster forecaster, java.util.List targetNames) which returns a JPanel

For example-

```
// Your instances
Instances train;
// Your WekaForecaster
WekaForecaster forecaster;
...
// Custom hold out set size
int holdOutSetSize = 1;

// Init evaluator
TSEvaluation eval = new TSEvaluation(train, holdOutSetSize);

boolean buildModel = false;

// Evaluate the forecaster
eval.evaluateForecaster(forecaster, buildModel, System.out);

// Get graph in JPanel after evaluation on training with custom hold out set size
JPanel trainGraph = eval.graphFutureForecastOnTraining(GraphDriver.getDefaultDriver(), 
                  forecaster, AbstractForecaster.
                  stringToList(forecaster.getFieldsToForecast()));
```

Cheers!

*References:* 
http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.packages/timeseriesForecasting/weka/classifiers/timeseries/eval/TSEvaluation.html